# Regex to dictionary on a pattern of strings

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

I am trying to PDF mining on an image and I have a text which looks like this.

```
30
ABC0690966
Name : Mario Doe Father's Name : John Doe House Number: 42 Age : 28
Gender: MALE
Name: Alex Ross Father's Name: Mike Ross House Number: 43 Age : 24 Gender :
FEMALE
Name : Sura vessi Father's Name : Jean vessi House Number: 44 Age : 29 Gender: MALE
Photo is Available
Photo is Available
Photo is Available
Age as on 01.01.2022
# - Modified as per supplement Date of Publication:-05-01-2022
Total Pages 31 - Page 3
Shipmemt No and Name : 93-Mombasa
Part number: 11
Section No and Name : 1-0c Colony
31
32
33
JFK1569730
RLKO182915
SLR0670463
Name : Yuri Ismailov Husband's Name: Boris Ismailov House Number: 46 Age: 34 Gender:
FEMALE
Name : Don Dudyadev Father's Name: Ray Dudyadev House Number: 50 Age: 36 Gender:
MALE
Name: Dragana vescez Husband's Name : Billy vescez Number: 55 Age : 34 Gender:
FEMALE
Photo is Available
Photo is Available
Photo is Available
34
KGD0588582
35
POR3232162
36
BAC1565423
Name : Yulia Bessi Husband's Name: monty Bessi House Number: 56 Age: 43 Gender: FEMALE
Name : monty Bessi Father's Name: Grande Bessi House Number: 57 Age: 43 Gender:
MALE
Name: Chrissy finch Father's Name : Sebastian finch House Number: 59 Age: 30 Gender:
FEMALE
Photo is Available
Photo is Available
Photo is Available
37
RISO188045
38
JOLO184622
39
CVB0425900
Name : Gandor Bristol Father's Name: Cyan Bristol House Number: 64 Age : 64 Gender:
MALE
Name : Ivan shamarov Father's Name: Vlad shamarov House Number: 64 Age : 42 Gender: MALE
Name : Maria shamarov Husband's Name : Daya shamarov House Number: 64 Age : 36 Gender:
FEMALE
Photo is Available
Photo is Available
Photo is Available
40
HVR3231990
41
ZYTO188052
42
RMSO188383
Name : Rocki Bakka Father's Name: Pete House Number: 68 Age : 58 Gender:
MALE
Name: Suki Shanka Husband's Name: Lenin House Number: 68
54 Gender: FEMALE
Name : Igor Shanka Father's Name : Pete Shanka House Number: 68 Age: 33 Gender:
MALE
Photo is Available
Photo is Available
Photo is Available
43
CLIO187906
44
GLOO184630
45
BAI1713973
Name : Sheldon Cooper Father's Name : George cooper House Number: 68 Age: 31 Gender: MALE
Name: Gerogie Cooper Father's Name: George cooper Number: 1-69 Age: 63 Gender: MALE
Name: Missy Cooper Husband's Name :  George cooper House Number: 1-69 Age: 58 Gender:
FEMALE
Photo is Available
```

These lines have a pattern, they have Name, Father's or Husbands Name, House Number, Age, Gender. There may be new line characters in text for Age or Gender at some places.

Some of these may be absent at times due to translation errors which I am okay with and I want to have NULL there.

My working solution right now have a regex pattern match which would find patterns like this 'ABC0690966', 'JFK1569730'

and for the rest, I am trying to use a lot of re.sub to replace Name with ,Name   Father's with ,Father's, House with ,House  Age with ,Age  Gender with ,Gender making it look like

```
,Name : Mario Doe ,Father's Name : John Doe ,House Number: 42 ,Age : 28
,Gender: MALE
,Name: Alex Ross ,Father's Name: Mike Ross ,House Number: 43 ,Age : 24 ,Gender :
FEMALE
,Name : Sura vessi ,Father's Name : Jean vessi ,House Number: 44 ,Age : 29 ,Gender: MALE
```

This helps me to Find all keys here and save it to list. This works but it is often messy.

Is there a neat way to achieve this?

Some thing like a dict which will iterate over all lines and appends all values to a dict key in python. Something like

```
rule = {'Name': text, 'Father's Name: text, 'House Number': text, 'Age': text, 'Gender': text}

text = ''',Name : Mario Doe ,Father's Name' : John Doe ,House Number: 42 ,Age : 28
,Gender: MALE'''

output = {'Name': 'Mario Doe', 'Father's Name': John Doe, 'House Number': 42, 'Age': 28, 'Gender': MALE}
```

Comment: You may have to create a very (long) specific regex, for example `r"(?:Father's Name|Husband's Name)\s?:\s?(?P<fathersName>.+?)House"` will capture Father's or Husband's name in a group called `fathersName` that later could help you to build the dictionary. You can follow the same idea and try to capture the whole thing in a single regex with named groups.

Answer (score 0):

I can only give you an idea of how to do that using regex. It is difficult however to capture inconsistent `n-words` before the `colon (:)`. Here I replace the words, `Father's Name, House Number` with `fathers_name, house_number` to match the regex pattern.

Here is the code:

```
import re

s = "Name : Mario Doe Father's Name : John Doe House Number: 42 Age : 28 Gender: MALE"
string = s.replace(' :', ':')
string = string.replace("Father's Name", 'fathers_name')
string = string.replace('House Number', 'house_number')
match = re.findall('(\w+):\s+(.*?)(?=$|\s*\w+:\s+)', string)

res = {match[i][0].lower(): match[i][1] for i in range(len(match))}
print(res)
```

Result:

```
{'name': 'Mario Doe', 'fathers_name': 'John Doe', 'house_number': '42', 'age': '28', 'gender': 'MALE'}
```